# Using variable (for loop) in Laravel's Query Builder

Tags: laravel, for-loop, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a query that needs to check multiple orWhere statements.

```
$cases = ['john', 'kate', 'mike', 'rob', 'josh', 'moe']
```

I want to use where as a for loop in this case.

```
Cat::where(function($q) use ($cases) {
   $q->where('name', 'john')->orWhere('name', 'kate'); // etc
})->get();
```

Is there a cleaner way to use this with a for loop so it chains `orWhere` on the fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code

```
Cat::whereIn('name', $cases);
```

If you wont you can use also this code

```
Cat::where(function($q) use ($cases) {
   $firstCase = array_shift($cases);
   $q->where('name', $firstCase);
   foreach($cases as $case) {
      $q->orWhere('name', $case);
   }
   // other conditions this
})->get();
```

Comment: Yeah - just realised that. For a second I thought that's only for `id`s. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop throw like this:

```php
Cat::where('name',function($q) use ($cases) {
  foreach($cases as $case) {
    $q->where('name', $case);
  }
})->get();
```

But `whereIn` is even simpler:

```php
Cat::whereIn('name', $cases);
```